# bootstrapping an ubuntu ec2 instance using chef and knife

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, chef

I am bootstrapping a ec2 ubuntu based chef node using chef, it creates an instance but it says `Failed to authenticate ubuntu - trying password auth`and asks for the password. But a newly created ubuntu ec2 instance will not have any kind of password set. Throws an error

```
ERROR: Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: ubuntu@ec2-184-72-72-163.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

How do I bypass this event and also whats the problem, do I have to make any changes in the configurations.

Kindly help me I am new to the chef.

Comment: are you even pointing to your ssh key you used to setup the ec2 instance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is you aren't using this

```
-i IDENTITY_FILE, --identity-file IDENTITY_FILE
The SSH identity file used for authentication. Key-based authentication is recommended.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use "ssh-agent" and use "ssh-add" on you private key to let ssh know you want to use it, without specifying the "-i" option with invocation of ssh.